# how to add an eventListener after looping over the fetch function in jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am struggling put an event listener to 'readMore' and 'readLess' link after loading the page
I gotta render the page first with the data from the local storage which is saved in another page.

What I wanna put the code in this files are as below

```
$(".readMore").click((event) => {
          event.target.style.display = "none";
          event.target.style.visibility = "collapse";
          $(".hidden-plot").css("visibility", "visible");
          $(".hidden-plot").css("display", "inline");
          $(".readLess").css("visibility", "visible");
          $(".readLess").css("display", "block");

        });

        // when user clicks read less btn, the contents will be collapsed
        $(".readLess").click((event) => {

          event.target.style.display = "none";
          event.target.style.visibility = "collapse";
          $(".hidden-plot").css("visibility", "hidden");
          $(".hidden-plot").css("display", "none");
          $(".readMore").css("visibility", "visible");
          $(".readMore").css("display", "block");
          
        });
```

This is js file what I am working on

```
import { createCustomObj, isPlotLongOrShort } from "/utils.js";
$(document).ready(() => {
  let savedMovies = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("movies"));

  for(let i=0; i<savedMovies.length; i++){

    fetch(`http://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=2cc10b4e&t=${savedMovies[i]}&plot=full`)
      .then((res) => res.json())

      .then((data) => {

        let newData = createCustomObj(data);
        let html = createHtmlCollection(newData)
        $( "#result-wrapper" ).append( html );
        $(".stars-inner").css("width", newData.Rating + "%");
       
      })

  }


function createHtmlCollection(obj){

    return `<div class="movie-result">
    <div class="movie-poster-sec">
            <img src="${obj.Poster}" alt="" class="movie-poster-img"/>
        </div>
  
        <div class="movie-info-sec">
            <div class="movie-info-header">
                <div class="movie-title-and-rating">
                    <h3 class='movie-title'>${obj.Title}</h3>
  
                        <div class="stars-outer">
                            <div class="stars-inner"></div>
                        </div>
                </div>
                <div class="movie-genre-and-runtime">
                    <h4 class='movie-genre'>${obj.Genre}</h4>
                    <h4 class='movie-runtime'>${obj.Runtime}</h4>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="movie-info-plot">
                <p class='movie-plot-p'>${isPlotLongOrShort(obj.Plot)}</p>
            </div>
        </div>`

}

});
```

I treid to put these lines after the loop is over, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two suggestions. First, define your listener up front as a [delegate](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) - which will work even if the elements being listened to aren't written to the DOM yet:

```
    $("#result-wrapper").on("click", ".readMore", function() {
      $(this).css({"display":"none", "visibility":"collapse"});
      $(".hidden-plot").css({"visibility":"visible", "display":"inline"});
      $(".readLess").css({"visibility":"visible", "display":"block"});
    });
```

The second suggestion is you collapse both read more and less into a single class/function

```js
$("#result-wrapper").on("click", ".moreToggle", function() {
  let showmore = $(this).data('readmore') == "1";
  $(this).data('readmore', showmore ? '0' : '1')
  $(this).text(showmore ? "Read less" : "Read more");
  let hideEl = showmore ? '.theless' : '.themore';
  let showEl = !showmore ? '.theless' : '.themore';
  $(this).closest('.item').find(hideEl).hide();
  $(this).closest('.item').find(showEl).show();
});
```

```css
.themore {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='result-wrapper'>

  <p class='item'>
    <span class='theless'>This is the short version</span>
    <span class='themore'>This is the long long long long long version</span>
    <a class='moreToggle' data-readmore='1' href='javascript:void(0)'>Read more</a>

</div>
```

Comment: First suggestion you gave me working well ;)